# Fill / complete / expand columnwise

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(lg0 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE), lg2 = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), lg4 = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), ld0 = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), ld1 = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), ld2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), ld4 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

    lg0   lg2   lg4   ld0   ld1   ld2   ld4
1 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
5  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
6  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
7  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

How can I add missing columns `lg1`, `lg3`, `ld3` filled with `FALSE`.

**I would like** to 'quasi' complete / fill / expand missing COLUMNS to have this:

This should be independent on which of the columns are not present, this can change.

**Desired Output:**

```
lg0   lg1   lg2   lg3   lg4   ld0   ld1   ld2   ld3   ld4  
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE
TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

**So far I have tried:**

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    everything()
  ) %>% 
  mutate(id = parse_number(name)) 

expand(df2, id, name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`, we can construct a new dataset of `FALSE` and assign the 'df' back to it based on the matching column names

```
nm1 <- paste0(rep(c("lg", "ld"), each = 5), 0:4)
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(FALSE, nrow = nrow(df), 
        ncol = length(nm1), dimnames = list(NULL, nm1)))
df2[names(df)] <- df
```

-output

```
> df2
    lg0   lg1   lg2   lg3   lg4   ld0   ld1   ld2   ld3   ld4
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
5  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
6  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
7  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

If we want to automatically construct the `nm1`

```
d1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", names(df)))
nm1 <- c(t(outer(unique(sub("\\d+", "", names(df))),  
      min(d1):max(d1), FUN = paste0)))
df[setdiff(nm1, names(df))] <- FALSE
df[nm1]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  extract(name, c("base", "pre"), regex = "(\\D+)(\\d+)") %>% 
  mutate(id = rep(1:ncol(df), each = ncol(df))) %>%
  group_by(id, base) %>%
  mutate(pre = as.integer(pre)) %>%
  complete(pre = seq(min(pre), max(pre), 1), fill = list(value = FALSE)) %>%
  unite("New_Name", c(base, pre), sep = "") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = New_Name, values_from = value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  relocate(starts_with("lg"))


# A tibble: 7 x 10
  lg0   lg1   lg2   lg3   lg4   ld0   ld1   ld2   ld3   ld4  
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
5 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE
6 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
7 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you dear Anoushiravan. Very impressive solution.

Comment: My pleasure dear friend, anytime :)